# Computing index of a closed curve (non linear dynamics)

Tags: differential-equations, non-linear-systems

My question is specific to the method for computing the index of a closed curve C with respect to a vector field in phase space as described in the book by Steven Strogatz (page 176).

[image]

Briefly, the protocol is to draw the vector field lines at certain points on the curve and label them. The fields are then arranged with their tails having a common origin and the number of rotations is calculated.

Here's my question: Is it not possible to miss complete rotations that may have occurred between two field lines?

Comment: How would you obtain the curve in the first place?

Comment: It's an arbitrary closed curve. More precisely, a simply closed curve that does not intersect itself. The aim is to calculate the total rotations traversed by the field lines along any arbitrary curve.

Comment: Sure, but you are asking about a problem arising when applying this method to some specific curve. Before this problem can arise, you have to obtain the curve somehow.

Comment: I may not have understood your question. I updated the figure that has the kind of curve that I'm talking about. How do you know if vector 4 is obtained through a -270 degree rotation of vector 3 or 90 degree rotation of the same (assuming rotation in counter-clockwise direction is positive)?

Comment: I just noted that the diagram doesn’t make any sense. The vector field should always be tangential to the curve (at least if the curve should have anything to do with the vector field).